# Move elements within dictionary of 2D Lists from a separate function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I'm currently writing a sokoban game in python, I'm new to the language and and I'm using a dictionary of lists to store my board and so far I've managed to get my character moving (albeit without any checks so far).

I am now trying to write a separate function that will allow the boxes to move position when the character is next to the box and the opposite side has a space.

I understand how to code the logic to perform those checks and task but I am unable to get my head around how I am able to access the player_position, box_position and my temp_board from my move_player() function in my move_box() function.

Could anyone possibly give me an idea on how to do this please? I tried making these global variables but then it would not be defined when instantiating it in the move_box() function

Here is my code: (I tried to set this up on python fiddle but it wouldn't let me share the link or run, sorry)

```
import copy

# Level constructs
r_t_corner = "\u2510"
l_t_corner = "\u250C"
l_b_corner = "\u2514"
r_b_corner = "\u2518"
v_wall = "\u2502"
h_wall = "\u2500"

# Game variables
player = "@"
box = "\u2588"
goal = "."
direction = ""


# Level Dictionary set up
levels = [{'board': [[l_t_corner, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall,     h_wall, h_wall, r_t_corner],
                 [v_wall, " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", v_wall],
                 [v_wall, " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", goal, v_wall],
                 [v_wall, " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", v_wall],
                 [l_b_corner, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, h_wall, r_b_corner]],
       'variables':{'player': [2, 2],
                    'boxes': [[1, 4]]}
       }
      ]

game_turn = 0


def print_level():

    level = levels[game_turn]['board']
    variable_positions = levels[game_turn]['variables']
    player_position = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player']
    box_positions = levels[game_turn]['variables']['boxes']

    temp_board = copy.deepcopy(level)
    temp_board[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] = player

    for i in range(len(box_positions)):
        temp_board[box_positions[i][0]][box_positions[i][1]] = box

    print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in temp_board))  # Test board printing ok


def move_player():
    global direction
    direction = (input("Please make a move using (w,a,s,d): "))

    # Right
     if direction == "d":
         col = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1] + 1
         row = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][0]
         if levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == h_wall or levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == v_wall:
             levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1]
         else:
             levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1] += 1

    # Left
    if direction == "a":
        col = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1] - 1
        row = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][0]
        if levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == h_wall or levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == v_wall:
            levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1]
        else:
            levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1] -= 1

    # Up
    if direction == "w":
        row = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][0] - 1
        col = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1]
        if levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == h_wall or levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == v_wall:
            levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1]
        else:
            levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][0] -= 1

    # Down
    if direction == "s":
        row = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][0] + 1
        col = levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1]
        if levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == h_wall or levels[game_turn]['board'][row][col] == v_wall:
            levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][1]
        else:
            levels[game_turn]['variables']['player'][0] += 1


def move_boxes(temp_board, player_position):
    # check what location player is, check location of box, push in row / column  facing
    if direction == "d":
        if temp_board[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] == box and     temp_board[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] == " ":
           temp_board[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] = player
           temp_board[player_position[0]][player_position[1] - 1] = box

            for i in range(len(box_positions)):
               if player_position == box_positions[i]:
                   levels[game_turn]['variable']['boxes'][i][1] -= 1

while True:
   print_level()
   move_player()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation; as written, `move_boxes` has no code in its body (actually, none of your functions do).

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry about that, I've fixed the indentation now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make them global (as you do with `direction`) or pass them as arguments between functions.

I don't understand the problem you had with making them global, but you haven't shown how you tried to do it.